# Solving for Roots in R- 3 variables

Tags: r

I'm trying to solve an equation with three variables in R. The equation is:
`59991348 * x^2 - 13958305552 * x + 992000000 + (6000000000 - Q * P) /(x * (.03 + 6000000000 - Q))`. Is there a way to solve it symbolically (x = etc), or find the roots, in R? I've downloaded deSolve but I'm unsure what commands would help. Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: you want to find the roots of `x` while treating `Q` and `P` as constants?

Comment: R is really not the tool for the job. Have you tried [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+59991348+*+x^2+-+13958305552+*+x+%2B+992000000+%2B+%286000000000+-+Q+*+P%29+%2F%28x+*+%28.03+%2B+6000000000+-+Q%29%29+for+x+#)? The roots are very convoluted.

Comment: This simplifies to a cubic equation.  It depends on what you want to do, but if you just need efficient numerical answers for a specified `P` and `Q`, you might just multiply it out and use `polyroot` ...

Comment: Thanks guys. Ben, Q and P are constants, yes. Mr. nograpes, I will give it a try. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't checked this at all, but it seems that [yacas](http://yacas.sourceforge.net/homepage.html) can do this, via the `Ryacas` package:

```
ff <- "Solve(59991348 * x^2 - 13958305552 * x + 992000000 + (6000000000 - Q * P) /(x * (.03 + 6000000000 - Q)),x)"
```

Then solve:

```
library("Ryacas")
ans0 <- yacas(ff)
ans1 <- gsub("([{}]|,$)","",strsplit(ans0$YacasForm,"x==")[[1]])
ans1 <- ans1[2:4]
grepl("Complex",ans1) ## FALSE TRUE TRUE
Sqrt <- function(x) sqrt(complex(real=x))
Complex <- function(r,i) complex(real=r,imag=i)
zapI <- function(x) if(Im(zapsmall(x))==0) as.numeric(x) else x
numAns <- function(y,P=1,Q=1) {
    zapI(eval(parse(text=y),list(P=P,Q=Q)))
}
numAns(ans1[1])  ## 232.6009
numAns(ans1[2])  ## -1.014755e-09
numAns(ans1[3])  ## 0.07109052
```

This is a bit clunky, maybe someone can do better ...

Comment: Hi Mr. Bolker:
Thank you for the response, but I noticed you declared P and Q equal to 1. Is it possible to keep them as variables in a function for the roots of x, yielding something like x = numbersQ + numbersP? Thanks again.

Comment: they are variables.  I set the default values to 1.  You can set them to whatever you want.  If you want to print out the whole symbolic expression for x as a function of y, P, and Q you can just print `ans1`, but it probably won't help you very much ...

Comment: Hello Mr. Bolker: I'm sorry to bug you again, but I can't get RYacas to function properly. I'm going to try another machine, but in the meantime, the equation has been rewritten to: 
59991348*x^2-13958305552*x+992000000+[(a-b)/x]/(0.02+c-a) = 0.
Would I be able to simply swap the equation you used for this one? Thanks for all your help.